# Problem with staticfiles while DEBUG=FALSE Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

When `DEBUG = TRUE` the site is working fine, but in my log file i have:

```
WARNING [django.server:154] "GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1717
```

When `DEBUG = FALSE` error 500 occurs and in log file i have:

```
ERROR [django.request:228] Internal Server Error: /topics/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 420, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Here my settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

os.makedirs(STATIC_TMP, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(STATIC_ROOT, exist_ok=True)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

In my base.html:

```
<link href="{% static '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I tried changing this line to:

```
<link href="static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The site has earned, but the errors in log file remain the same. 
And in CLI i have:

```
The system cannot find the specified path: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\my_project\\staticfiles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this command:

> python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: but this is for DEBUG = True mode, with whom I have no problems. And I do not use user-uploaded files.

Comment: in production mode must read from static folder. in debug mode you don't need static folder

Comment: i did what you advise, the problem was not solved. I run the site from a local server even when DEBUG=False, and everything is going well. but on the heroku server still error.

Comment: i change my answer